# How to allow horizontal scrolling in a web page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm planning to display a table with a large width, so I havent' founded a CSS o HTML code to display this table and can move in a horizontally way

[image]

The only part which should be with horizontal scrolling is in the center (the white color). Here is my defaul razor view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("MS. GARCIA MATH 7TH", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>...</nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            ...
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap it in a div of limited width

Answer (score 5):

Set overflow to scroll

```
#body{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overflow scroll

```
table
{
 overflow: scroll;
}
```